# Unable to fix frame size in app - customtkinter, tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm working on an app to covert some files. The interface consists of two frames - one that displays selected files, the other will contain parameters the users can modify (e.g. file pre-fix, location etc.).

I'd like the `frame` width and height to be fixed (300px each) but it changes when I add widgets to them (shown in screenshot below). I'm open to using `tkinter` instead of `customtkinter` if that will solve the issue.

Code:

```
# define colour palette
app_color = '#121212'
frame_color = '#1e1e1e'
text_color = '#e3e3e3'
label_color = '#a8a8a8'
accent = '#bb86fc'
dark_grey = '#423e47'

# Fonts 
font_small = ('Segoe UI', 16)
font_reg = ('Segoe UI', 18)    

# Declare App
app = ctk.CTk(fg_color=app_color)
app.title('File Converter')
app.geometry('720x480')

""" Frame 1 for selecting file to confirm  """
multiple_files = ctk.CTkFrame(master=app, fg_color=frame_color, 
                              width=300, height=320, corner_radius=10)
multiple_files.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(40,20), pady=40)

file_label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=multiple_files, text='Select Files', text_color=text_color, 
                          font=font_small, anchor='nw')
file_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

lb = tk.Listbox(master=multiple_files, bd=0, selectbackground=dark_grey)
lb.grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan=3, padx=(20,20), pady=(20,20))

# button to add files
btn_add = ctk.CTkButton(master=multiple_files, text='Add', width=50,
                              command=addFiles, fg_color=accent,
                              text_color=app_color)
btn_add.grid(row=2,column=0, padx=10, pady=(0,20))

# button to remove files 
btn_remove = ctk.CTkButton(master=multiple_files, text='Remove', width=50,
                              fg_color=accent, text_color=app_color, 
                              command=removeFiles)
btn_remove.grid(row=2,column=1, padx=10, pady=(0,20))

# button to clear files 
btn_clear = ctk.CTkButton(master=multiple_files, text='Clear', width=50,
                                    fg_color=accent, text_color=app_color, 
                                    command=clearFiles)
btn_clear.grid(row=2,column=2, padx=10, pady=(0,20))

""" Frame 2 for conversion parameters  """

opts_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=app, fg_color=frame_color,
                          width=300, height=320, corner_radius=10)
opts_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(20,40), pady=40)

app.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent container will be resized by default when child widgets are added into it using `.pack()` or `.grid()`.  It can be override by calling `.pack_propagate(0)` or `.grid_propagate(0)` respectively on the parent container:

```py
multiple_files.grid_propagate(0)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, any suggestions on how to remove border from the `listbox` - I've tried `bd=0` but it still shows up.

Comment: @Gautam It is not the border, but highlight background.  Set `highlightthickness=0`.